# Does every normed linear sequence space has unit norm vector with only one non zero term.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

When we talk about usual sequence spaces equipped with some norm, for instance $\ell^p$ spaces, we know there are elements $(e_n)_n$, which have all their terms zero except $n-th$ term and its norm is 1. I wonder if every non trivial sequence space equipped with a nontrivial norm has such an element i.e. a vector $e$, all whose terms are zero except one term and its norm is 1.

Comment: Your question is very dependent on the coordinates, choice of basis and the understanding of "terms" of "non-trivial sequence spaces". For example how would you answer this question for the space $\{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2~:~ x_1-x_2=0\}$ ?

Comment: Yes thank you. I got it.

Comment: What about the closed subspace $\{ x \in \ell^1 \mid \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n = 0\}$?